# Show view with two different JSON array in Angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two different JSON Array and I want to use it in my view using ng-repeat.

I have *first JSON* array as text values which I am using for creating the number of fields.

```
["center", "80mm", "retain", "22pt", "bold", "140%", "18pt", "bold", "140%", "36pt", "11pt", "bold", "normal", "absolute", "211mm", "20mm", "20mm", "20mm", "center", undefined, undefined, "end-on-even", "even-page", "9pt"]
```

I got *seconds JSON* array for labels which I am confused how to use it in my view.

```
["text-align", "space-before", "space-before.conditionality", "font-size", "font-weight", "line-height", "font-size", "font-weight", "line-height", "space-before", "font-size", "font-weight", "line-height", "position", "top", "bottom", "right", "left", "text-align", "", "", "force-page-count", "break-before", "font-size"]
```

***As my second JSON array is referred to as key and first JSON as value.***

This is what I am doing in my **view**:-

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="record in textvalue track by $index">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1" ng-repeat="records in attrnames">{{records}}</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                <option>{{record}}</option>                             
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**EDIT added controller  mapping of two arrays:-**

```
$scope.textvalue = $scope.jsonObj.stylesheet['attribute-set']
                .map(x => {
                    if (Array.isArray(x.attribute))
                        return x.attribute.map(y => y['__text']);
                    else
                        return [x.attribute['__text']]; 
                })
                .reduce((accu, cur) => accu.concat(...cur), []);
                console.log($scope.textvalue);


            //filter out names
            $scope.attrnames = $scope.jsonObj.stylesheet['attribute-set']
                .map(x => {
                    if (Array.isArray(x.attribute))
                        return x.attribute.map(y => y['_name']);
                    else
                        return [x.attribute['_name']]; 
                })
                .reduce((accu, cur) => accu.concat(...cur), []);
                console.log($scope.attrnames);
```

Comment: Ue a single array of objects, where each object contains an attribute name (text-align for example) and its corresponding value (center for example). Parallel arrays are almost always a design mistake.

Comment: @JBNizet I am using mapping to extract out different key values , how can I combine in the same mapping. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

can you use this code snippet

```
 $scope.labelValue = ["center", "80mm", "retain", "22pt", "bold", "140%", "18pt", "bold", "140%", "36pt", "11pt", "bold", "normal", "absolute", "211mm", "20mm", "20mm", "20mm", "center", undefined, undefined, "end-on-even", "even-page", "9pt"];

$scope.property = ["text-align", "space-before", "space-before.conditionality", "font-size", "font-weight", "line-height", "font-size", "font-weight", "line-height", "space-before", "font-size", "font-weight", "line-height", "position", "top", "bottom", "right", "left", "text-align", "", "", "force-page-count", "break-before", "font-size"];
```

HTML Snippet:

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="label in labelValue">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">{{property[$index]}}</label>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>{{label}}</option>                             
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Didn't worked .. showing only labelValue . Actually labelValue is property.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module("MyApp",[])
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.arrjson1 =["center", "80mm", "retain", "22pt", "bold", "140%", "18pt", "bold", "140%", "36pt", "11pt", "bold", "normal", "absolute", "211mm", "20mm", "20mm", "20mm", "center", "undefined", "undefined", "end-on-even", "even-page", "9pt"]
;
   $scope.arrjson2 = ["text-align", "space-before", "space-before.conditionality", "font-size", "font-weight", "line-height", "font-size", "font-weight", "line-height", "space-before", "font-size", "font-weight", "line-height", "position", "top", "bottom", "right", "left", "text-align", "", "", "force-page-count", "break-before", "font-size",];

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span ng-repeat="x in arrjson2 track by $index">
      {{x}} : <span><b>{{arrjson1[$index]}}
</span><br/>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No , actually `"text-align":"center", "space-before":"80mm"`  respectively. got it. So there is one:one

Comment: Done ! Please check

Comment: This is correct but this is not I want. I need this in my input field.  `text-align` will be label and  `center` will be the input field with only one  so that I can change the value of `center` and respectively one on one. Earlier what you did was correct with all the values in options , just that there should be `text-align` against one option that is `center` and respectively

Comment: Or else I  have less knowledge in mapping with 2 values , if you map my edit i have added in my question  and make it to single JSON it will be helpful uisng single ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Do not need two `ng-repeat` for this scenario. You can use the index for global ng-repeat

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="record in attrnames track by $index">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">{{records}}</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                <option>textvalue[{{$index}}]</option>                             
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: but `attrnames` is different JSON array. let me try

Comment: but the values are same in both arrays

Comment: It's like this way `"text-align":"center", "space-before":"80mm` so options or input will be the value and label will be the key

Comment: @WhoAmI I have updated my answer. you just need change the array name

Comment: No it's not working . `textvalue` is completely different array. I need to combine as said.